# Another pivot SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I cannot quite get my had around previous examples, unfortunately.

I am trying to create a table based on the voting for baseballs MVP over the years and comparing it with a more objective measure WAR now available. I want to see the difference between the two top ranked players according to this value. Here is code to show just a couple of years of many

```
select season,division,player,rankMVP as MVP,WAR,rankWAR 
 from mlbmvpvoting
where   (season = '1955' or season = '1956')
and rankWAR < 3
order by season,division,rankWAR

season division   player                   MVP  WAR  rankWAR
1955    AL  Mickey Mantle                   5   9.5     1
1955    AL  Al Kaline                       2   9.0     2
1955    NL  Willie Mays                     4   9.3     1
1955    NL  Duke Snider                     2   8.9     2
1956    AL  Mickey Mantle                   1   12.9    1
1956    AL  Early Wynn                      13  8.5     2
1956    NL  Duke Snider                     10  7.7     1
1956    NL  Hank Aaron                      3   7.5     2
```

I want to produce something like this

```
season   division  pl_1         pl_2     MVP_1   MVP_2   WAR_1   WAR_2  
 1955      AL  Mickey Mantle  Al Kaline   5      2       9.5      9.0
 1955      N   Willy Mays     Duke Snider 4      2       9.3      8.9
```

etc

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grouping and conditional aggregating, like this:

```
SELECT
  season,
  division,
  pl_1  = MAX(CASE rankWAR WHEN 1 THEN player  END),
  pl_2  = MAX(CASE rankWAR WHEN 2 THEN player  END),
  MVP_1 = MAX(CASE rankWAR WHEN 1 THEN rankMVP END),
  MVP_2 = MAX(CASE rankWAR WHEN 2 THEN rankMVP END),
  WAR_1 = MAX(CASE rankWAR WHEN 1 THEN WAR     END),
  WAR_2 = MAX(CASE rankWAR WHEN 2 THEN WAR     END)
FROM mlbmvpvoting
WHERE season IN ('1955', '1956')
  AND rankWAR IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY season, division
ORDER BY season, division
```

`IN` is basically more optimisable than `OR` and `<`, so I changed the conditions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for that . I just extended to all seasons with WHERE season IN (select distinct season
FROM mlbmvpvoting
) and was away.   If anyone is interested in an analysis using the results - particularly pertaining to Willie Mays - I have blogged about it here http://tinyurl.com/6kr28dl

Answer (score 0):

See if such a solution suits you:

```
with mlbmvpvoting (season, division, player, MVP, WAR, rankWAR) as 
(
    select 1955,    'AL', 'Mickey Mantle',  5,   9.5,     1  union all
    select 1955,    'AL', 'Al Kaline',      2,   9.0,     2  union all
    select 1955,    'NL', 'Willie Mays',    4,   9.3,     1  union all
    select 1955,    'NL', 'Duke Snider',    2,   8.9,     2  union all
    select 1956,    'AL', 'Mickey Mantle',  1,   12.9,    1  union all
    select 1956,    'AL', 'Early Wynn',     13,  8.5,     2  union all
    select 1956,    'NL', 'Duke Snider',    10,  7.7,     1  union all
    select 1956,    'NL', 'Hank Aaron',     3,   7.5,     2
)
select
    season, 
    division,
    pl_1  = max(case rankWAR when 1 then player end),
    pl_2  = max(case rankWAR when 2 then player end),
    MVP_1 = max(case rankWAR when 1 then MVP end),
    MVP_2 = max(case rankWAR when 2 then MVP end),
    WAR_1 = max(case rankWAR when 1 then WAR end),
    WAR_2 = max(case rankWAR when 2 then WAR end)
from mlbmvpvoting
group by season, division
order by season;
```